# Javascript store user inputs into array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I want to save user inputs in an array so that later I can edit the table from the array. Each row will have a different ID.

```js
//here is the full code of add_row() function

function add_row() 
{
 var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
 if(code == "")
 {
  alert("code empty!");
  return false;
 }
 else if(isNaN(code))
 {
  alert("code must be numbers");
        return false;
 }
 
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
 if(name == "")
 {
  alert("name empty!");
        return false;
 }
 else if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name.replace(/\s/g, '')))) 
 {
  alert("name must be letters");
  return false;
 }
 
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
 if(year == "")
 {
  alert("year empty!");
        return false;
 }
 else if(isNaN(year))
 {
  alert("year must be angka");
  return false;
 }
 
    var major = document.getElementById('major').value;
 if(major == "")
 {
  alert("major empty!");
        return false;
 }
 
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
 if(address == "")
 {
  alert("address empty!");
        return false;
 }
 
 var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
 var et = email.indexOf("@");
 var dot = email.indexOf(".");
 if(email == "")
 {
  alert("email empty!");
        return false;
 }
 else if (et < 1 || dot<et+2 || dot+2>email.length) 
 {
  alert('email harus mengandung @ dan domain');
  return false;
  console.log('failures');
  }
 
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
 if(phone == "")
 {
  alert("phone empty!");
        return false;
 }
 else if(isNaN(phone))
 {
  alert("phone harus angka diisi dengan angka");
  return false;
 }
 
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length / 2 + 1);
 
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='code_row"+table_len+"'>"+code+"</td><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+name+"</td><td id='year_row"+table_len+"'>"+year+"</td><td id='major_row"+table_len+"'>"+major+"</td><td id='address_row"+table_len+"'>"+address+"</td><td id='email_row"+table_len+"'>"+email+"</td><td id='phone_row"+table_len+"'>"+phone+"</td> <td onload='hide_save("+table_len+")'; 'hide_save("+table_len+")'><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 console.log('failures');

 var codeArr, nameArr, yearArr, majorArr, addressArr, emailArr, phoneArr;
 codeArr = [];
 nameArr = [];
 yearArr = [];
 majorArr = [];
 addressArr = [];
 emailArr = [];
 phoneArr = [];

}
```

```html
<!--Here is the form for add-->
<!--Add----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

      <!--Modal pop UP-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add</h4>
        </div>

        <!--Body pop up-->
        <div class="modal-body">

          <form id="myForm">
            Code :
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Code" name: "Code" id="Code">

            <br>Name :
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name " name: "Name" id="Name">

            <br>Year :
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Year" name: "Year" id="Year">

            <br>Major :
            <br>
            <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Major" name: "Major" id="Major">-->
            <form action="/action_page.php" name: "Major" id="Major">
              <select name="Major" id="Major">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select>
            </form>

            Address :
            <br>
            <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Address" name:"Address" id="Address">-->
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Address" name: "Address" id="Address"></textarea>

            <br>Email :
            <br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">

            <br>phone :
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="phone" name: "phone" id="phone">
          </form>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" onClick="reset()" id="btnReset" style="background-color:#800003" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="add_row()" id="btnSave" style="background-color:#003300" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of Add---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

And I wanted to save those inputs into array like

```js
var ArrCode = [];
```

so when the user press save button, the array will be filled like

```
ArrCode = [input1, input2, input3, etc];
```

*I am not sure whether I will create another variable or not, so I will just make it.

Please let me know if you need more snippet.

Comment: instead of calling the JS code from within the html, it is a better idea to create event listeners for your functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, if have got your point**

```
codeArr[table_len] = code;
nameArr[table_len] = name;
```

not sure, if am right as per your need